# Monogo DB Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js

I needed a property of date/time which would allow to me get the time at which a certain task was created, I added timestamp property and set it to be true,
But I m not able to compile my code.

The code is perfectly running fine without the timestamp property[image: Error I m getting is]

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Task = mongoose.model(
  "Task",
  ({
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      minLength: 100,
    },
    completed: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true })
);

module.exports = Task;
```

I needed a property of date/time which would allow to me get the time at which a certain task was created, I added timestamp property and set it to be true,
But I m not able to compile my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongoose.model() function of the mongoose module is used to create a collection of a particular database of MongoDB. The name of the collection created by the model function is always in plural format mean GFG to gfss and the created collection imposed a definite structure.

Syntax:

```
mongoose.model(<Collectionname>, <CollectionSchema>)
```

Parameters: This function accepts the following two parameters:

**Collection name:** It is the name of the collection.

**Collection Schema:** It is the schema of the collection.
Return type: This function returns the Mongoose object.
You need to pass a valid schema for the second argument like below

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const TodoModel = mongoose.model(
      "Task",
      new mongoose.Schema(
        {
          title: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
          },
          description: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
            minLength: 100,
          },
          completed: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
          },
        },
        { timestamps: true }
      )
    );

    module.exports = TodoModel;
```

More about what is a valid schema refer below
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html